# How can I prevent that my checkout saves the data of the user?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

If the user decides to enter his payment information(in the checkout process) and then leaves the checkout process to reopen the checkout later, all information he entered are still there. Duo some bugs I want that the information will be cleared after he leaves the checkout process. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the checkout session.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();
```

**I hope this will help you.**